# Getting Error "App Not Installed", after upgrading the android platform

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am getting error "App Not Installed" after android platform updated from 7.1 to 8.0

Plese find the logs for the same below

> 2019-07-06 19:57:24.583 1553-1740/? W/PackageManager: Package com.xxx.projectname new target SDK 19 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 26 does.
>   2019-07-06 19:57:24.587 977-1852/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl102287624.tmp: No such file or directory
>   2019-07-06 19:57:24.591 1553-1665/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
>   2019-07-06 19:57:24.591 1553-1665/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 480
>   2019-07-06 19:57:24.591 1553-1665/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
>   2019-07-06 19:57:24.593 1553-2694/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {dat=file:///data/user_de/0/com.google.android.packageinstaller/no_backup/package3167777381408856548.apk flg=0x2000000 cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFailed (has extras)} from uid 10035
>   2019-07-06 19:57:24.597 1553-2694/? D/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: Activity is Triggerred in full screen ApplicationInfo{82c36ee com.google.android.packageinstaller}
>   2019-07-06 19:57:24.597 1553-2694/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFailed/28

Comment: Could you please create a [_Minimal, Reproducible Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you’re currently facing so that we can recreate the issue?

Comment: i was building an app in ionic, and due to android platform to new version, when i installed the new app over the existing installed app, it gives me the error of app not installed

Comment: also i cannot uninstall the app manually as its a rollout version

Comment: also have update the logcat for the same

Comment: @SajeedShaikh I faced the same issue. Reason of this issue was that I was using a few plugins which were not supported on the latest Android version. can you check if your any plugin is pointing to the specific android version?